# Why is the android sdk failing to install?

Tags: android, macos, android-sdk-2.3

I am setting up my android development environment using these instructions:
http://developer.android.com/sdk/installing.html

When I get to step 4, and type 'android' I get the following error:

```
/Users/user1/programming/android\ development/android-sdk-linux_x86/tools/android ; exit;
user1-Macbook-Pro:~ user1$ /Users/user1/programming/android\ development/android-sdk-linux_x86/tools/android ; exit;
Starting Android SDK and AVD Manager
No command line parameters provided, launching UI.
See 'android --help' for operations from the command line.
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no swt-gtk-3550 or swt-gtk in swt.library.path, java.library.path or the jar file
    at org.eclipse.swt.internal.Library.loadLibrary(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.swt.internal.Library.loadLibrary(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.swt.internal.C.<clinit>(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.swt.internal.Converter.wcsToMbcs(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.swt.internal.Converter.wcsToMbcs(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.<clinit>(Unknown Source)
    at com.android.sdkmanager.Main.showMainWindow(Main.java:297)
    at com.android.sdkmanager.Main.doAction(Main.java:281)
    at com.android.sdkmanager.Main.run(Main.java:99)
    at com.android.sdkmanager.Main.main(Main.java:88)
logout

[Process completed]
```

It's like the android sdk is not aware of the ecplise libraries.  I have downloaded and installed eclipse.  Any ideas why this is failing?

Comment: i don't know mac but it looks like your missing the gtk libraries.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You downloaded the wrong sdk.  Make sure to download the Mac OS X (intel) SDK.

Comment: Thanks Jacksonh.  I figured this out sometime ago but never updated this question.

Answer (score 2):

From your pasted output:

`user1-Macbook-Pro:~ user1$ /Users/user1/programming/android\ development/android-sdk-linux_x86/tools/android ; exit;`

are you trying to use the Linux SDK under OS X? You can get the OS X SDK from the download page here: http://d.android.com/sdk/index.html